# How to fix weird icons in pcmanfm-qt on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: icons, qt, 22.04

I made a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install and I see that the icons in `pcmanfm-qt` are somehow odd and most of them are missing:

[image]

I crawled around a bit and found a few packages, whose missingness could be the problem.

```
lxmenu-data 
lxqt-qtplugin 
libqt5svg5-dev 
cdtool
```

Unfortunately after installing and reboot and pcmanfm-qt reinstall the problem remains. Any ideas?

Comment: You've tagged `pcmanfm` an older GTK2 program? and not the Qt5 `pcmanfm-qt` you mention.. Is there a reason?  Lubuntu provides `lxmenu-data` & `lxqt-qtplugin` on new installs; as `pcmanfm-qt` handles the LXQt desktop (*also acts as file-manager*); starting as a fork of `pcmanfm` & the prior LXDE desktop (*it was dual purpose there too*); it was the same LXDE *devs* that ported it & reused some work, eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/lxmenu-data was re-used as it was mostly generic.

Comment: What have you set as your Qt Style?  Qt5 icon theme?   I do see one no-icon-found *replacement* displayed on your screen...

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, that was a mistake. I removed the tag. What do you mean by setting a Qt style? I was not prompted about anything like that and I cannot find it in the menus. I found `FallbackIconThemeName=oxygen` in .config/pcmanfm-qt/settings.conf.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop uses GNOME by default, thus uses GTK3/GTK4 settings; `pcmanfm-qt` instead uses Qt5 settings & LXQt settings by default (*expected given it's the LXQt desktop icon manager that also performs file-manager functions too*)- which your system (GNOME/GTK) doesn't set.  `pcmanfm-qt` expects you to set settings using `lxqt-config-appearance` found in the package `lxqt-config`; however it can also be setup by other apps too (KDE also shares Qt5 settings having it's own as well as KDE uses KF5 that LXQt doesn't). Defaults get stored in `~/.config/lxqt/` impacting all LXQt apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to @guiverc 's comment.

I could edit the icon settings all I want using `lxqt-config-appearance` to no effect. The reason was that the environment variable `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt` needed to be set.

To always launch `pcmanfm-qt` with this variable I created a `.desktop` entry:

```
cp    /usr/share/applications/pcmanfm-qt.desktop \
  ~/.local/share/applications/pcmanfm-qt.desktop
```

And edit the `Exec` line in the newly created file:

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt pcmanfm-qt "%U"
```